# How to dynamically populate an array in Typescript for ngx chart?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I am using ngx chart library to display a barchart. It works fine when I use a static array but when I try to populate it dynamically, it does not work.

Below are my codes:

Note: allProducts is an array returned from API with a list of itemName, AmountPaid, Date purchased, etc. I only need the array below with itemname and amountpaid to populate a bar chart using ngxChart.

When I use this static array, everything works fine:

```
        this.products = [{
            "name": this.allProducts[0].itemName,
            "value": this.allProducts[0].AmountPaid
        },
            {
                "name": this.allProducts[1].itemName,
                "value": this.allProducts[1].AmountPaid
            }
            ,
            {
                "name": this.allProducts[2].itemName,
                "value": this.allProducts[2].AmountPaid
            }
            ,
            {
                "name": this.allProducts[3].itemName,
                "value": this.allProducts[3].AmountPaid
            }
            ,
            {
                "name": this.allProducts[4].itemName,
                "value": this.allProducts[4].AmountPaid
            }
            ,
            {
                "name": this.allProducts[5].itemName,
                "value": this.allProducts[5].AmountPaid
            }
        ];
```

When I try to create it dynamically as below - it does not return the array in the correct format:

```
        this.allProducts.forEach((item) => {
            this.productData.push({
                "name": item.itemName,
                "value": item.grossAmountPaid
            });
        })
```

The console.log for the static array returns the below - **correct format**:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Car-SL-Monthly", value: 1000000}
1: {name: "Car-SL-Yearly", value: 1000000}
2: {name: "Car-RB-Monthly", value: 5000}
3: {name: "dsaf", value: 455}
4: {name: "Delivery Van", value: 500000}
5: {name: "Lorry", value: 1000000}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The dynamic array returns the below - Incorrect Format:

```
Array(6)
0: {name: "Car-SL-Monthly", value: 1000000}
1: {name: "Car-SL-Yearly", value: 1000000}
2: {name: "Car-RB-Monthly", value: 5000}
3: {name: "dsaf", value: 455}
4: {name: "Delivery Van", value: 500000}
5: {name: "Lorry", value: 1000000}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What is wrong with my foreach loop and how can I get my dynamic array (using foreach) to be in the same format as the static array?

Comment: What do you mean by correct/incorrect format? Both outputs are identical in their data.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike I agree, but look at the first line - it seems to have a different header.

Comment: Maybe you should stop relying on the format of your console logs

Answer (score 1):

in your type script file------

```js
    charDataLoading: boolean ; // define a variable

    constructor(){
    this.chartDataLoading = true; // set variable value false 
    }
     ngOnInit(){
               this._createChartData();
    }
     private _createChartData(){
     this.allProducts.forEach((item) => {
                this.productData.push({
                    "name": item.itemName,
                    "value": item.grossAmountPaid
                });
            })
    this.chartDataLoading = false;
    }
```

Use chartDataLoading as condition variable in your html file

```html
<div *ngIf="!chartDataLoading">
//put your chart canvas inside this div 
</div>
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

In static version you are using

> this.products

and in dynamic version you have

> this.productData

Also maybe array push method not triggering change detection. try something like this and let us know.

```
this.productData = this.allProducts.map((item) => ({
            "name": item.itemName,
            "value": item.grossAmountPaid
        }));
```